# Can not browse wifi network

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, internet, connection

I use Ubuntu 13.04 Linux operating system and when I connect the wireless network in my home, my phone (android) or other devices can not browse, but when I disconnect my computer from wireless network everything is okay. how can I fix it?

Comment: Isn't an IP address conflict an option? Are you sure you did not assign the same address to multiple devices?

Comment: I use dual boot with windows 8, when i reboot my computer in windows 8 all of my home devices works normally. this happens only when Ubuntu connected to network, all devices connect but internet is down but ubuntu has maximum internet speet. I dont think this is ip problem

Comment: Did you check that? You IP can be different on both OS. Maybe you're using the same address as your default gateway

Comment: how can i check this?

Comment: Windows: ipconfig
Unix: ifconfig
Also check your router/gateway IP configuration. You'll probably have web interface based config